# How to use another version of library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, qmake, shared-libraries

I have libpng 1.12 installed (on Ubuntu by apt-get) in my `/usr/lib` directory. I want to use 1.14 so i downloaded it, compiled and installed to `/usr/local/lib`. How can I make my compiler/linker will use the library from /usr/locla?

I have tried to do it a "stupid" way- change link from `/usr/lib/libpng.so` from `/usr/lib/libpng12.so` to `/usr/local/lib/libpng.so`. Program compiles and runs (with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`) but there is a warning that says it was compiled with previous version and runs with the newer one.

How can I do such thing properly? ( I am using qmake project on Ubuntu 12.04)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to (1) compile (2) link and (3) load using the new version.

To compile against the new version, use `-I/path/to/includes/of/new/version` flag (probably `-I/usr/local/include` in your case).

To link against the new version, use `-L /path/to/libs/of/new/version` linker flag (`-L /usr/local/lib` in your case).

There are various methods to load the new version, the easiest one is probably to use `-rpath` linker flag. If you link with `gcc` or `g++`, use it like this: `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib`. If you are using `ld`, use just `-rpath=/usr/local/lib`.

Do **not** touch things in `/usr/lib`, you will be burned after the next software update, and you may break existing software.

You don't need to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH if you use -rpath. You may use one *or* the other.

Answer (score 1):

When linking your application, instead of using `-lpng` use `/usr/local/libpng14.so` or whatever name and path you are using.

Comment: Just "-lpng14" ought to work, too.  But if you are doing new development you might consider using libpng16 which is the current version.

Comment: all your answers are good. Glenn's hint is the simpliest i suppose, thanks a lot